# Unable to use Alamofire on CocoaTouch Framework

Tags: swift, xcode6, alamofire, cocoa-touch

Im working on a custom CocoaTouch Framework **in swift** thats include several frameworks like AFNetworking, SwiftyJSON and many others added with CocoaPods. I need also include Alamofire but after build I receive a lot of compile error of Alamofire framework
[image]

What's wrong? Should I edit something in my project?
Steps to reproduce: Create CocoaToch Framework Project > pod install with pod 'Alamofire' and platform :ios, '8.0' use_frameworks! > open xcworkspace > Build

I really appreciate any help you can provide

Marco

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of the podfile so I can have a look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to get latest version of the Alamofire which supports XCode 7. So you should fetch the specific version. Try to download this version:

```
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 1.3'
```